# Sample size calculation for 3 arm study "non-inferiority design" and continuous endpoints

Tags: r, sample-size, non-inferiority

I need to do a sample size calculation for a 3 arm study.

Something like mentioned [HIER](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22764073)!

The endpoint is a severity score. The score can take integer values from 0 to 100 points. (i would consider this "continuous"?)

The three arms are Gold-standard, New Drug and Placebo.

Are there any implementations of the in the paper mentioned methods in R or some other software.

Any **practical** pieces of advice on how to progress here?

Best wishes
André

Comment: Usually requests for code or R packages are seen as off-topic here. You might get a better response on an R mailing list.

Comment: Thank you. I'm open to any language or software that can do the sample size calculation. If I just bound myself to R I probably miss out on something.